# How to create a playable pool cue for second life

Tags: linden-scripting-language

Well as the title says i want to make a pool cue that will actually hit the balls on my table.
I have made the billiard table and the balls. The problem is i cannot think of how to attach the cue to my arm so that it can hit the balls. I know that attached objects cannot invoke collisions so i shouldn't attach it? I am bit stuck.. 
Does anyone have any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try asking in the SLHelpDesk group if you can't find an answer anywhere else.  They have some folks who are great with scripting and building.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment Tom. You need a second life account to ask them or there are specified forums? The thing is i don't have a second life account. I work with OpenSim.

Comment: You can get a SecondLife account free here: `http://join.secondlife.com/?lang=en-US`.  It would be worth having if you plan on interacting with the SL Community.

Comment: Please complete if this question has been answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to try. Make the sticks be objects the players can sit on. The object can then get control permissions to the players' keys: asdf or arrows and shift-arrows to turn and move sideways. You could make a mode that makes sure the stick always points at the cue ball and the only thing the player has to do is aim and shoot. Set the player's eye point and look-at relative to the stick. Mouseclick or enter shoots. You'll have to find a way to make the angle setup fine enough to be useful.

The cue could shoot a particle. Or it could send a message to the cue ball and make it move. Do you trust SL physics?

Comment: good thinking, as avatar position would be terribly otherwise! offsetting the sit position and coordinating the avatar pose/animation will be .. as difficult as ever, but looks much better than having avatar walking around randomly!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the objects settings, for example if the attachment is phantom or you have set llVolumeDetect(true) see [Collisions](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Collision).

My thoughts on this would be to use camera point and click and pass angle and force info onto the ball and let it figure out where to go.. the cue would simply would then just be an animated attachment with a bit of camera controls... therefore no need for collisions.

As a side note having the balls set as physical would be they can detect a collision with each other and react and would react with the non physical table too.

if you provide a bit more detail on the settings i will be able to be more specific :)
hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your relpy. What i did is this. I made the attachement (aka the cue) a gun which fires invisible projectiles. The projectiles then hit the balls, which are already be set to physical, and the balls move. Since the whole thing is done in mouselook it looks realistic enough.

Comment: Yes that should work, however firing projectiles to hit little ball's would have to be extremely accurate taking into account the Avatar height but that is doable it does just all boil down to the maths involved.  Using the suggestion above would simply pass on the info with a [llCastRay](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LlCastRay) to the first intersection and send the force angle (ie. position of Avi) to know which direction the ball has to go... Relying on SL physics may mean your pool balls don't roll as far as you would hope unless they have made it better recently.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [llCastRay](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LlCastRay) instead of shooting physical objects. You can still calculate impact and forward that as a message to the balls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually attach it, and yet have it perform physical collisions with the cue ball (or others), one way to do that is to launch a small invisible sphere down the length of the pool cue. However, the position and orientation of the pool cue is not well known when attached, and with vary with animations, etc. If you had a specific "pool shot" pose, you could hard-code the rotation of the invisible collider with the pool cue.

However, it would probably be best if you proceeded with an approach *other than* attaching/wearing the pool cue.  Perhaps a HUD with positioning arrows (that can also optionally respond to key presses) that rezzes and positions a pool cue.  That pool cue could actually apply a force to the ball using the rotation of the cue and the position of the tip.  Alternatively, it could launch a small invisible sphere down the length of the pool cue shaft, although that would require rez permissions.  I would probably use the last approach there.